Nvim Lazyvim activate Obsidian Plugin only with Obsidian
I am still new to LazyVim. Still struggling with my first unanswered question: From vim to nvim LazyVim - plugins help needed
I activated Obsidian plugin, which is very nice. But it removes YAML Headers from all my Markdown files, when saving the file. How to enable Obsidian Plugin only, when in my Obsidian Folder?

You’ll most likely need to consult your plugin documentation for that (linked under :help local-additions, if memory serves, which is somewhere on the main :help page).

Assuming that the plugin you are using is epwalsh's obsidian.nvim, you need to add the following lines to your obsidian options:
  lazy = true,
  event = {
    "BufReadPre " .. vim.fn.expand "~" .. "path/to/my/vault/*.md",
    "BufNewFile full/path/to/my/vault/*.md",
  },

(Note that vim.fn.expand "~" .. "path/to/my/vault/*.md" and "full/path/to/my/vault/*.md" are interchangeable).
So as an example, in your init.lua file, you may have:
require("lazy").setup({
  {
    "some/other-plugin",
    opts = {},
  },
  {
    "epwalsh/obsidian.nvim",
    lazy = true,
    event = {
      "BufReadPre full/path/to/my/vault/*.md",
      "BufNewFile full/path/to/my/vault/*.md",
    },
    dependencies = { "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" },
    opts = {
      workspaces = {
        {
          name = "my-vault",
          path = "~/path/to/my/vault"
        },
      },
    },
  },
})

Source: https://github.com/epwalsh/obsidian.nvim#using-lazynvim

Does Lua also use .. for string concatenation? TIL

@D.BenKnoble Yep :) Concatenation - Lua 5.4 Manual

thx acid_tigR for your elaborate reply.
I tried once again, to reactivate epwalsh/obsidian.nvim. Unfortunately it was still not working. I struggled to get back my 160 lines of yaml headers in an other folder than my Obsidian. I have had to disable the plugin Obsidian, to get back my headers. Luckily I have had a backup to get the headers back. This plugin is toxic!
I suppose, I have to escape the spaces in my Obsidian path like this: /Users/<user>/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Obsidian. Right? Perhaps I will try it again, this time on a test document.

@MarekStepanek No, you don't have to escape any spaces. The ~ represents the home path (C:/Users/<user>/) and vim.fn.expand "~" just converts ~ to C:/Users/<user>/. I have also struggled with this plugin
